# How to replace drush_download_file in Drush 9

Tags: drush

`drush_download_file()` existed in includes/drush.inc for Drush 8 and below, but this has been removed in Drush 9 as far as I can tell.

Is there a standard way that file downloads should be executed in custom commands written for Drush 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Drush 9 dropping support for the `drush dl` command, the need for keeping a download function was dropped.

The remnants of `drush_download_file()` were dropped into the [`SyncViaHttpCommands.php`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/Commands/SyncViaHttpCommands.php) example class to demonstrate creating a custom a Drush commandfile. You could copy that as a template if you're looking to mimic the old `drush_download_file()`, or you could use the Guzzle client or some other PHP function; use what works best for your command's download needs.

Comment: Nice find.  Very insightful.  Thank you.